# Use PostgreSQL Domain and Struct types in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, orm, jpa, eclipselink

After creating EntityManagerFactory instance, I receive error message:

```
...
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [aPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7157] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Entity class [class Table] must use a @JoinColumn instead of @Column to map its relationship attribute [Price].
...
```

Column Price is Domain type (example: `CREATE TYPE MONEY AS NUMERIC(10,2) FINAL`).

How to use Domain or Struct PostgreSQL types? Is it possible with JPA?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question... but are you actually doing `create type money`? could be a problem that [money](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-money.html) is a valid postgres type already (although I believe it's considered something you shouldn't use)

Comment: No it's just example. I use: 
CREATE DOMAIN "public"."price" AS numeric(12,2);
PostgreSQL has solid built in support for user-defined data types, but I would like to know how to use them in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not really with the column type, at least that's not what JPA is complaining about for now, the problem is that JPA doesn't know how to map a `Price` type which is not one of the basic supported type, nor an Entity.

> #### 2.1.1 Persistent Fields and Properties
>
> The persistent fields or properties of
>   an entity may be of the following
>   types: Java primitive types;
>   `java.lang.String`; other Java
>   serializable types (including
>   wrappers of the primitive types,
>   `java.math.BigInteger`,
>   `java.math.BigDecimal`,
>   `java.util.Date`,
>   `java.util.Calendar`,
>   `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time`,
>   `java.sql.Timestamp`, user-defined
>   serializable types, `byte[]`,
>   `Byte[]`, `char[]`, and `Character[]`; enums; entity
>   types and/or collections of entity types; and embeddable classes (see section 2.1.5).

With standard JPA, try to use the `Embeddable` and the `Embedded` annotations:

```
@Embeddable
public class Price {
    private BigDecimal amount;
    ...
}
```

and then in your entity:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="amount", column=@Column(name="AMOUNT"))
})
public Price getPrice() { ... }
```

The other option would be to use a [`TransformationMapping`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/1.1/org/eclipse/persistence/annotations/Transformation.html) (EclipseLink specific).

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - 2.1.5 Embeddable Classes
  - 2.1.6 Mapping Defaults for Non-Relationship Fields or Properties
  - 9.1.34 Embeddable Annotation
  - 9.1.35 Embedded Annotation

Comment: OK. I'll use your references to find solution.
Thanks for help.